# How to import HTML Table from Outlook for a specified Date into Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to import HTML tables from emails into Excel.

I stumbled onto code here that will import all html tables from a selected folder. I would like to add an option to select a specified date.

Have added the following line

```
If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("Email_ReciptDate").Value Then)
```

I get an error.

```vb
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMapi As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim tables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim destCell As Range

With ActiveSheet
    Set destCell = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
End With
   
On Error Resume Next
Set oApp = GetObject(, "OUTLOOK.APPLICATION")
If oApp Is Nothing Then Set oApp = CreateObject("OUTLOOK.APPLICATION")
On Error GoTo 0

Set oMapi = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder

If Not oMapi Is Nothing Then

    For Each oMail In oMapi.Items
    
        If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("Email_ReciptDate").Value Then
        
            'Get HTML tables from email object
        
            Set HTMLdoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
            With HTMLdoc
                .Body.innerHTML = oMail.HTMLBody
                Set tables = .getElementsByTagName("table")
            End With
    
            'Import each table into Excel
        
            For Each table In tables
                For x = 0 To table.Rows.Length - 1
                    For y = 0 To table.Rows(x).Cells.Length - 1
                        destCell.Offset(x, y).Value = table.Rows(x).Cells(y).innerText
                    Next y
                Next x
                Set destCell = destCell.Offset(x)
            Next
        End If
    Next
        
    MsgBox "Finished"
    
End If

Set oApp = Nothing
Set oMapi = Nothing
Set oMail = Nothing
Set HTMLdoc = Nothing
Set tables = Nothing
```

Comment: be more clear please, about what kind of modification you want to achieve.

Comment: Basically what i am trying to achieve is to be able to combine the HTML body from 2 emails into a single email. And then sending it out. However it seems that this is just extracting the HTML inner text into excel. Is there a way i can simply just grab the HTML tables from both emails and combining them into 1(retaining the original table format)

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over all items in the folder and checking whether a particular item corresponds to the condition in the code is not really a good idea! Instead, I'd suggest using the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the `Items` class. For example:

```
Public Sub ContactDateCheck()  
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace  
    Dim myContacts As Outlook.Items  
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items  
    Dim myItem As Object  
      
    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
    Set myContacts = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items  
    Set myItems = myContacts.Restrict("[LastModificationTime] > '01/1/2021'")  
    For Each myItem In myItems  
        If (myItem.Class = olContact) Then  
            MsgBox myItem.FullName & ": " & myItem.LastModificationTime  
        End If  
    Next  
End Sub
```

Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Also you may find the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method of the Outlook `Application` class helpful. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) for more information and sample code.